# Significant performance differences with "Predict" function between v10 and v11

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, version-10, version-11

So I am very new to ML. I tried running this code in Mathematica 10.4.1.0

```
input = Table[
   RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[Random[Real, 5], Random[Real, 2]],
     100], {jj, 1, 2000}];
output = Table[Mean[input[[ii]]], {ii, 1, Length[input]}];
data = input -> output;
p = Predict[data, Method -> "NeuralNetwork", 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];
test = Table[
   RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[Random[Real, 5], Random[Real, 2]],
     100], {jj, 1, 10000}];
testoutput = Table[Mean[test[[ii]]], {ii, 1, Length[test]}];
Mean[Abs[(p[test] - testoutput)]]
StandardDeviation[Abs[(p[test] - testoutput)]]
Median[Abs[(p[test] - testoutput)]]
```

It returns values on the order of 0.09 for the mean absolute difference. When I run the same code in Mathematica 11.2, I get values of about 0.9 for the mean absolute difference.

I understand, the training set is small. Does anyone know a possible reason for this different behavior? I guess s default setting has been changed in the operation of "Predict?"

Comment: Mathematica 11 what? 11.0? 11.2?

Comment: Updated question to reflect this. Sorry.

Comment: I don't know the specifics, but I do think that between 10 and 11 they tried to move this type of function more towards the neural network functionality as its backend, and that functionality is constantly in flux. I would maybe report it to tech support and they can comment on whether its a regression or not.

Comment: I Just discovered it goes beyond just this. In 10 I can use the option "Method -> {"NeuralNetwork", "HiddenLayers" -> {{2, "Linear"}}}"
This functionality no longer works in 11.